# probability of five people meeting at train station

Tags: combinatorics, geometric-probability

Five people all go to the same train station on their way to work. Each of them will arrive at a random time from 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM and stay for exactly 12 minutes, independent of all the others. Find the probability that at some point, all five people are at the train station.

I'm having trouble with this question. Normally, you can solve these questions with geometric probability, but this doesn't work because there are five people. How do I solve this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483678/geometric-probability-in-morethan-3-dimensions?rq=1

Comment: Maybe it will help to note that the five people are all at the train station at some point if the range of their arrival times is less than 12 minutes.